# CUDA error: "no kernel image is available for execution on the device" - which PyTorch version to use?

Tags: machine-learning, python, pytorch, cuda, amazon-ml

I'm running some ML python code on Amazon's EC2 - the machine has a GPU: NVIDIA A10G. The ML code is written using PyTorch.

When I run the code I get error:

`CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device`

I suppose this is about PyTorch version? Used version is `torch==1.10.2`.

How do I know which version of PyTorch the code MUST use? What's the error about?

Are there certain requirement for CUDA by this GPU (A10G)?